# Rails controller params conditionals - how to do this cleanly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I'm need to check a bunch of conditions in a controller method.  1) it's a mess and 2) it's not even hitting the right redirects.

```
def password_set_submit
  password_check = /^(?=.*[a-z]{1,})(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*\d{1,}){8,}.+$/

  @user = User.find(session[:id])
    if params[:password] && params[:password_confirmation] && params[:username] && params[:old_password]
        if params[:password] == params[:password_confirmation] && params[:password] =~ password_check

          # do some api stuff here

        if @user.save
          flash[:success] = 'Password updated.'
          redirect_to login_path and return
        end
      end
      if params[:password] != params[:password_confirmation]
        flash[:error] = 'Passwords did not match.'
        redirect_to password_set_path and return
      end
      if params[:password] == params[:password_confirmation] && params[:password] !~ password_check
        flash[:error] = 'Passwords did not match password criteria.'
        redirect_to password_set_path and return
      end
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Please fill all inputs.'
    redirect_to password_set_path and return
  end
end
```

This needs to do the following:

1) If less than four params submitted, redirect and display 'Fill all inputs'

2) If password and password confirmation don't match each other,  redirect and display 'Password did not match'

3) If password and password confirmation match each other but do not match criteria, redirect and display 'Passwords did not match criteria'

4) If password and password confirmation match each other and match criteria, make api call and redirect to login

I'm out of if/else ideas and I hope cleaning this up will help me nail the redirects correctly.

Comment: From a UX perspective, I would do the criteria check (on primary password parameter only) ahead of the confirmation check. If I'm failing both, I'd like to know I've picked an invalid password first. (That said, I'm also immensely frustrated by arbitrary password requirements (beyond minimum length) and password confirmation fields, so I'd challenge the existence of both, at least in a production environment.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll switch them.

Answer (score 2):

The Rails way to this is by using model validations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :password, confirmation: true, presence: true# password must match password_confirmation
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true # a password confirmation must be set
end
```

If we try to create or update a user without a matching pw / pw confirmation the operation will fail.

```
irb(main):006:0> @user = User.create(password: 'foo')
   (1.5ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<User id: nil, password: "foo", password_confirmation: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):007:0> @user.errors.full_messages
=> ["Password confirmation can't be blank"]
irb(main):008:0>
```

### However

When dealing with user passwords you should **NEVER NEVER NEVER** store them in the database in plain text!

Since most users reuse a common password you might also be compromising their email, bank account etc. You could potentially be held financially and legally responsible and it can destroy your career.

The answer is to use an encrypted password. Since this is incredibly easy to get wrong Rails has something called `has_secure_password` which encrypts and validates passwords.

The first thing you want to do is to remove the `password` and `password_confirmation` columns from your `users` database.

Add a `password_digest` column. And then add `has_secure_password` to your model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  PASSWORD_CHECK = /^(?=.*[a-z]{1,})(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*\d{1,}){8,}.+$/
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, format: PASSWORD_CHECK
end
```

This will automatically add validations for the password, confirmation and getters and setters for `password` and `password_confirmation`.

To check if the old password is correct we would do:

```
@user = User.find(session[:id]).authenticate(params[:old_password])
# user or nil
```

This is an example of the Rails way of doing it:

```
class UsersController

  # We setup a callback that redirects to the login if the user is not logged in
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :password_set_submit ]

  def password_set_submit
    # We don't want assign the the old_password to user.
    unless @user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
      # And we don't want to validate on the model level here
      # so we add an error manually:
      @user.errors.add(:old_password, 'The current password is not correct.')
    end
    if @user.update(update_password_params)
      redirect_to login_path, notice: 'Password updated.'
    else
      # The user failed to update, so we want to render the form again.
      render :password_set, alert: 'Password could not be updated.'
    end
  end

  private 

  # Normally you would put this in your ApplicationController 
  def authenticate_user!
    @user = User.find(session[:id])
    unless @user
      flash.alert('You must be signed in to perform this action.')
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters
  def update_password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Notice how the logic in our action is much much simpler? Either the user is updated and we redirect or it is invalid and we re-render the form.

Instead of creating one flash message per error we display the errors on the form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: { action: :password_set_submit}, method: :patch) do |f| %>

  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>Your password could not be updated:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :password, 'New password' %>
    <%= f.password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field_tag :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Please provide your current password for confirmation</p>
    <%= f.label :old_password, 'Current password' %>
    <%= f.password_field_tag :old_password %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Update password' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please note that this is a generalized example of how rails apps are commonly built - it is not complete or even guaranteed to work. Most of the rails basics in are explained much better than I ever could in Michael Hartl's free [Rails Tutorial book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). Please respect that my time and energy is limited and don't ask me to debug actually implementing it in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.  I didn't make it clear in my original post that the user and password are actually getting passed to an api endpoint, so I do not have access to the model.

Comment: To clarify, I'm working on a Rails app that uses an .NET API for user authentication and so on.  There is pressure to move away from using our "Rails tables" in favor of passing everything to the the API.  I can't run any validations because validations run when trying to save a model, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all code related to this password reset from the controller and put into its own model `User::PasswordReset`:

```
# in app/models/user/password_reset.rb
class User::PasswordReset
  attr_reader :user, :error

  PASSWORD_REGEXP = /^(?=.*[a-z]{1,})(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*\d{1,}){8,}.+$/

  def initialize(user_id)
    @user  = User.find(user_id)
  end

  def update(parameters)
    if parameters_valid?(parameters)
      # do some api stuff here with `user` and `parameters[:password]`
    else
      false
    end
  end

private

  def valid?
    error.blank?
  end

  def parameters_valid?(parameters)
    parameter_list_valid(parameters.keys) &&
      password_valid(params[:password], params[:password_confirmation])
  end

  def parameter_list_valid(keys)
    mandatory_keys = [:password, :password_confirmation, :username, :old_password]

    unless mandatory_keys.all? { |key| keys.include?(key) }
      @error = 'Please fill all inputs.'
    end

    valid?
  end

  def password_valid(password, confirmation)
    if password != confirmation
      @error = 'Passwords did not match.'
    elsif password !~ PASSWORD_REGEXP
      @error = 'Passwords did not match password criteria.'
    end

    valid?
  end

end
```

That would allow to change the controller's method to something simpler like this:

```
def password_set_submit
  password_reset = User::PasswordReset.new(session[:id])

  if password_reset.update(params)
    flash[:success] = 'Password updated.'
    redirect_to(login_path)
  else
    flash[:error] = password_reset.error
    redirect_to(password_set_path)
  end
end
```

Once you did this refactoring it should be much easier to find problems in your conditions and to extend your code.

Comment: Or he could use [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) and avoid totally comprising his users other accounts (Email, Facebook etc.) in the event of an attack... just sayin.

Comment: @maxcal : He did not share his code that actually update the password. How do you tell that he does not use `has_secure_password` or something similar?

Comment: `params[:password] =~ password_check` gives me a pretty strong indication of that.

Comment: You can't match a password from params if you are using encryption. Well unless you are using two way encryption - which is also not secure.

Comment: `params[:password]` is the new password that the user just send from a web form. As long as you do not encrypt passwords in the browser, it is pretty standard that is is not encrypted yet. We do not know how that password might be stored within the user model. I would expect that he uses `has_secure_password` to do so. But that discussion is out of scope of this question. This question is not about how to store the password in the model, but about improving the handling of the password before is it passed and encrypted in the model.

Comment: You're correct that password security is somewhat out of scope - and service objects (which is what your code kind of is) are awesome. But in this case it's a pretty heavy handed solution for something which can easily done by adding a few validations to the user model.  It also does not really address the case that the user can have several errors.